# Why is $mg = bv$ and not $mg = -bv$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, drag

I was given two formulas,

$$F_D = -bv $$
$$F_D = -bv^2 $$

and was told that at terminal velocity,

$$v = \frac{mg}{b} $$

which implies that

$$mg = bv$$
$$mg + (-bv)=0$$
$$mg + F_D = 0$$

From that equation, if I were to draw a free body diagram, $mg$ and $F_D$ will be in the same direction. Or am I misunderstanding somewhere?

Comment: Something that always helps me is to think not of equations full of letters, but to think about their meanings.  It's far easier to have an intuition about things when you know what they mean.  (For instance, without knowing the meanings, I find the first two equations fascinating, because it implies that v=0... but that may be because I'm misinterpreting their meaning)

Comment: $mg$ and $F_D$ are not in the same direction because they have the opposite sign.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\hat z$ be the unit vector which points vertically downwards.

The terminal velocity $v\hat z$ is downwards and the frictional force $F_{\rm D}$ has to act in the opposite direction (upwards) to the direction of motion (downwards) so $\vec F_{\rm D} = - bv\hat z$ with both $b$ and $v$ being positive.

Applying Newton's second law when the acceleration is zero gives

$$m \vec g + \vec F_{\rm D} =0 \Rightarrow mg \hat z + (-bv\hat z) = 0 \Rightarrow mg-bv =0 \Rightarrow mg = bv$$

Answer (score 0):

mg obviously points down.  However, the drag force resists the gravitational force ... otherwise, the falling object would continue accelerating rather than reaching a constant terminal velocity.  This means that the drag force equals the gravitational force and points in the opposite direction of the gravitational force when terminal velocity is reached.  The relevant equation from a free body diagram is $F_D - mg = 0$, assuming that up is the positive direction.  This equation obviously leads to the following, at terminal velocity: $F_D = mg$.

Answer (score 0):

> Or am I misunderstanding somewhere?

Sometimes, notation is ambiguous and then you must use physical *intuition*.

On intuitive physical grounds, the drag force due to the air can only *reduce* the acceleration due to gravity rather than *enhance* it, correct?

So, if $v$ is the *speed* of the object, the you should expect that there is a speed at which the drag force and gravitational force are equal in *magnitude* while *opposite* in direction, correct?

At this (terminal) speed, the is no net force on the object and thus, no acceleration, i.e., the object asymptotically approaches the terminal speed (either from above or below).

Answer (score 0):

This illustrates two different ways I typically see people do problems like these:

1) All symbols are positive. We use the sign in front of the symbol to denote direction

2) The sign is contained within the expression for each symbol, so we just add everything together.

It looks like your work uses the second convention, but either is correct and is reasonable. You just have to stay consistent.

For example, in my current work I am modeling ion flows into and out of my cells. I am actually using the first convention where positive means flow into the cell and negative means flow out of the cell. I think in this instance the first convention makes sense, since anyone reading the equations can know which direction currents are flowing, even if they do not know the expressions for the individual terms.
$$\frac{dc}{dt}=J_{IPR}+J_{lk}-J_{SERCA}$$
Without knowing what each term is exactly, you can tell which ones cause a flow inward and which are outward. But I could just have easily made all terms positive and then had the signs in the actual expressions for those terms.

So in your case, you can either chose (with down positive and up negative):
$$mg-F_D=0$$
$$F_D=bv$$

Or you can do
$$mg+F_D=0$$
$$F_D=-bv$$

Either way your equation is $mg-bv=0$, so you have the same physics.